# Trouble toggling class to DOM elements in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a small `sidebar` element to a web page which has multiple hidden `.sidebar-contents`. What it does, is reveal `.sidebar-contents` within a few seconds of delay between each items whenever I click on the button. Then hides the content in reverse order right after clicking the button again.

It worked just fine in my first try, but when I try it multiple times, it looks like class is being added twice in the `sidebar`. I bet I'm doing something wrong here but I don't have a clue.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
const SIDEBAR_DELAY_TIME = 150;

function handleSidebar() {
  const btn = document.querySelector('button');
  const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
  const contents = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar-element');

  if (!btn || !sidebar) return;

  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!sidebar.classList.contains('active')) {
      sidebar.classList.add('active');
      contents.forEach((item, i) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          item.classList.add('active');
        }, i * SIDEBAR_DELAY_TIME);
      });
    } else {
      const keys = Array.from({
        length: contents.length
      }, (_, i) => i);
      keys.reverse();

      keys.forEach((key, i) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          contents[key].classList.remove('active');
        }, i * SIDEBAR_DELAY_TIME);

        if (key === 0) {
          contents[0].addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
            sidebar.classList.remove('active');
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

handleSidebar();
```

```css
:root {
  --transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 450px;
  transform: translateY(55px);
  transition: transform var(--transition), opacity var(--transition);
  opacity: 0;
}

.sidebar.active {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar-element {
  padding: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  transform: translateY(64px);
  transition: transform var(--transition), opacity var(--transition);
  opacity: 0;
}

.sidebar-element.active {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button>click me</button>

<aside class="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-element">
    Element A
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-element">
    Element B
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-element">
    Element C
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-element">
    Element D
  </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: Every time your "click" handler runs, you add *another* "transitionend" handler. All of them will run when that event fires.

Comment: The above. To be clear, that means, once added, it will run on that element for all transition-ends, not only for the 'else' part (setting inactive). Meaning that the second run, for setting active, sidebar is set inactive again after that element is positioned

Comment: thank you for the explanation! it really helped a lot. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
          contents[0].addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
            sidebar.classList.remove('active');
          });
```

You are adding the `transitionend` listener multiple times. And the event is triggered after animations in both directions end. This ensues chaos.

You need to remove the listener after the transition ends

```
  const transitionend = () => {
    sidebar.classList.remove('active');
    contents[0].removeEventListener('transitionend', transitionend)
  };
// ...
contents[0].addEventListener('transitionend', transitionend)
```

```js
const SIDEBAR_DELAY_TIME = 150;

function handleSidebar() {
  const btn = document.querySelector('button');
  const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
  const contents = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar-element');

  const transitionend = () => {
    sidebar.classList.remove('active');
    contents[0].removeEventListener('transitionend', transitionend)
  };
  if (!btn || !sidebar) return;

  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!sidebar.classList.contains('active')) {
      sidebar.classList.add('active');
      contents.forEach((item, i) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          item.classList.add('active');
        }, i * SIDEBAR_DELAY_TIME);
      });
    } else {
      const keys = Array.from({
        length: contents.length
      }, (_, i) => i);
      keys.reverse();

      keys.forEach((key, i) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          contents[key].classList.remove('active');
        }, i * SIDEBAR_DELAY_TIME);

        if (key === 0) {
          contents[0].addEventListener('transitionend', transitionend)
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

handleSidebar();
```

```css
:root {
  --transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 450px;
  transform: translateY(55px);
  transition: transform var(--transition), opacity var(--transition);
  opacity: 0;
}

.sidebar.active {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar-element {
  padding: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  transform: translateY(64px);
  transition: transform var(--transition), opacity var(--transition);
  opacity: 0;
}

.sidebar-element.active {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button>click me</button>

<aside class="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-element">
    Element A
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-element">
    Element B
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-element">
    Element C
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-element">
    Element D
  </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: oh my god thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the transition-end is attached each time the 'set inactive' block is executed. That means that not only it is attached multiple times, but also that it will run for the 'set active' part after that.

One solution would be to add it once, not in the click event. Also below is a quickly gobbled up suggestion to prevent repetition of code (might need some tweaking)
Amongst others, by introducing a helper function to set the class of an element to whatever the status is (with 'toggle' )

```js
const SIDEBAR_DELAY_TIME = 150;

function handleSidebar() {
  const btn = document.querySelector('button');
  const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
  const contents =  document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar-element'), count = contents.length;

  if (!btn || !sidebar) return;

    let active = false;
  const set = el => el.classList.toggle('active',active);
  contents[contents.length-1].addEventListener('transitionend', () => set(sidebar));
          
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    active=!active;
    if (active) set(sidebar);      
      contents.forEach((item, i) => {
        setTimeout(() => set(item), (active ? i : count - i) * SIDEBAR_DELAY_TIME);
 
  });
});
}

handleSidebar();
```

```css
:root {
  --transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 450px;
  transform: translateY(55px);
  transition: transform var(--transition), opacity var(--transition);
  opacity: 0;
}

.sidebar.active {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar-element {
  padding: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  transform: translateY(64px);
  transition: transform var(--transition), opacity var(--transition);
  opacity: 0;
}

.sidebar-element.active {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button>click me</button>

<aside class="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-element">
    Element A
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-element">
    Element B
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-element">
    Element C
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-element">
    Element D
  </div>
</aside>
```